# jQuery comparison operator

Tags: jquery

The following works partially:

```
($(".call_1") || $("#call_1")).click(function(evt) 
      {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#championSlideshow, #pourSlideshow, #skimSlideshow").fadeOut(0,function()
        {
         $("#prepareSlideshow").fadeIn();
             console.log(prepare);
        });
   });
```

It picks up `#call_1` but no when I click on `.call_1`

Is the syntax wrong maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I think you intended to use the "[multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)":

```
$("#call_1, .call_1").click(function(evt) {

});
```

In your current code, the evaluation of `($(".call_1") || $("#call_1"))` will simply return `$(".call_1")`, as both calls will return a jQuery object, which will always be truthy.

Comment: +1 For explaining why it doesn't work. Maybe should add why the second expression isn't evaluated (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

`$(".call_1") || $("#call_1")` should be `$(".call_1, #call_1")`.

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order.

Here's a simple [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uhS5C/1/).

Answer (score 2):

try it as

```
$('.call_1, #call_1')
```

it will work for both `.call_1` and `#call_1`